# проблема с ботом экономики

Tags: python

Помогите, я написал код который выводет баланс учасника но почемуто он не работает, ошибки вроде никакой не выдавало но почемуто не хотел выдавать команду. заранее спасибо.
вот код:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT,
    id INT,
    cash BIGINT,
    rep INT,
    lvl INT
    )""")
    connection.commit()
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
            else:
                pass
connection.commit()
print('Я зайшов в систему')
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
        connection.commit()
    else:
        pass

@client.command()
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс учасника **{ctx.author}** є **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс учасника **{member}** є **{cursor.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]} :leaves:**"""
        ))
```

Comment: Проверьте табуляции у строк `connection.commit()` и `print('Я зайшов в систему')`, наверное эти строки относятся же к функции `on_ready`? А с такими табуляциями как сейчас, они у вас сами по себе.

Comment: Нет, я уже пробовал так зделать нечего не дало

Comment: Тогда подробно опишите весь юзе-кейс: Что вы делаете, что вы ожидаете получить, и что в реальности получаете. Сейчас из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно в чём у вас собственно проблема.

Comment: Я делаю економику сервера, и это баланс который должен выводитса на сервер в таблице, но у меня почемуто не выводитса когда я пишу команду баланса, и может ктото знает проблему и вот почему я сюда написал.